# pictures disappearing from Microsoft word 2010 document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, pictures

I have a problem with Word 2010 where the pictures disappear sometimes.  Here's how it usually happens:

1. open a document (everything you can initially see is ok)
2. zoom or scroll --> pictures disappear, leaving only frame

they may reappear if you zoom to another size.

have experienced the problem with multiple documents from multiple sources over a period of years.  tried the documents on a new copy of office 365 on another computer and it displays correctly regardless of zoom.

i work from home so i have very few computers to test it with.  i have a copy of office 2007 i may be able to try it with.

have "googled" this and tried the things I found online without any success.

thank you for your help!

Comment: Try narrow down the problem. Does this happen with just one document or with all that you try? Does it happen on just your machine or others? Can you find any pattern?

Answer (score 1):

This might well be a video driver problem.  To test, choose FILE | OPTIONS | ADVANCED

Scroll down to DISPLAY on the right and put a check next to "Disable hardware graphics acceleration".

Click OK and restart Word.  With luck, that'll sort things out.

If not, try testing Word in safe mode.  Hold down CTRL while you start Word.  When you see a dialog asking if you want to start Word in Safe Mode, answer Yes.

Comment: Could be; today, with the newest MS Word and a different computer, it's no longer a problem.

Comment: Please tell about differences between the old and new  computers - this might give a clue where the problem actually was.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have this turned on:

[image]

Comment: It isn't selected.  just reopened the document i worked on a short time ago and the other pictures are gone now (they were ok before!).

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to be a memory exhaustion problem.

Just a few images in a Word document will set quite high demands on available memory.
Not just RAM but also Graphics (hardware and driver) related memory.

So; The remedy: **Make sure to have enough RAM for the task at hand.**

Anything else to do? -> generally grows into an memory optimization nightmare.

Answer (score -2):

Try this ...

Click on the picture,

Then **Format tab** ...

click **Wrap Text** in the Arrange group.

Choose "In line with text."